# Perl Json Array

Tags: json, perl

I have an array of json objects in json format and in a file.
I'm trying to load the file into perl, cycle through each item of the array (each json object) ...

I've used the code bellow, but it seams that no matter what I do, perl is treating it not as an array of objects, rather as a big object. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
my $json_text = do {
   open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename)
      or die("Can't open \$filename\": $!\n");
   local $/;
   <$json_fh>
};

@objects = JSON->new->utf8->decode($json_text);
print  Dumper(@objects);
```

Comment: can you post the dumper output, maybe we find a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your file contains a single JSON array. In that case your call to `decode` will return a reference to a Perl array, so if you write

```
my $objects = JSON->new->utf8->decode($json_text)
```

you can access each object as `$objects->[0]`, `$objects->[1]` etc. Or you can iterate over them with

```
for my $object ( @$objects ) {

    # Do stuff with $object
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, I've never used perl and trying to take over some code that was written by another developer. All the @$% signs in perl are new to me. I'm guessing @$ dereferences a pointer to an array?

Comment: @MehdiAbderezai: Perl was designed by a linguist so each identifier has a singular form `$scalar` (read *this scalar*), an unrelated plural form `@array` (read *these array items*) and a dictionary form `%hash`. It's built-in [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). So to acccess one element (singular) of an array (plural) you write `$array[0]` etc. And yes, `@$` dereferences an array reference, but it's best to read `@$objects` as *the items in `$object`*, just as `@array` is *the items in `array`*